# How to use Flipboard effect on Android

Tags: android, effects, flipboard

I really like some effects in iPad. Especial flipboard, but I am an android developer at the moment, so I want to build an app which has the same effect. But I cannot find any source code about it on the Internet. On youtube I found a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4laKdWwTzP8) I really like. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Hey… [Here](http://openaphid.github.com/blog/2012/05/21/how-to-implement-flipboard-animation-on-android/) is a quick guide for getting the clipboard effect on your Android phone. Just go through this tutorial for getting it. Hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

http://openaphid.github.com/blog/2012/07/27/how-to-handle-touch-events-for-flip-animation/ there u go, but it is on opengl, and i'm not sure if it supports complex views as ListView. If you want to make one from the scratch i also recommend you this link. It is on Flex, but the principle is similar. http://oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/archive/flashhacks.html?page=1